# Android: Storing an array with the app

Tags: android, arrays

I have an array of data 10,000 entries long. This data almost never changes and I could handle it in the app if it did anyway. It seems unnecessary for me to store this on an external database considering it is just string data so wont be large.

Is there a way of storing this on the users phone with the app. I was thinking the string resources or a csv file. But these don't seem like the quickest or best option. What are the considerations I need when deciding whether to upload it to a database vs storing it on the device. Currently I use DynamoDB so searching the array on many attributes would be difficult.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why don't you use sqlite

Comment: @Sarthak I never new thank was possible internally thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data will not be change in future . Means its static then put Data in on string.xml

**OR**

If your data will be change in future then go with it database .....

Answer (score 1):

I would go with storing `Strings` in a `String-Array` in your `Strings.xml`like so:

```
<resources>
 <string-Array name ="data">
  <item> Data 1 </item>
  <item> Data 2 </item> 
  <item> etc etc </item> 
 </string-array>
</sesources>
```

and then within your class you would reference the array and store that array into your `List`

```
 List<String> stringData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data)));

 for (String row : stringData){
         Log.d("Data", row);
 }
```

if you're coding this from a `Fragment` I suggest using `getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.data)` or pass the context to your `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the size of your data (10,000), it's not good to use string resources.Also, your data are static which mean they will be access by read only. So it's better to use a file or Sqlite.However, if you do lot of queries to your data such as finding a specific entry, I encourage you to use Sqlite, because you can use SQLite index to query data faster, speed up sort...